# NetBeans "link with editor" feature

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

I use mostly Eclipse and have played around a little bit with NetBeans. The feature I have missed most is the "link with editor" which Eclipse has but I haven't found in NetBeans. The idea is that if I turn "link with editor" on, the editor window will always be in sync with the tree view on the left side (in Eclipse it's called "package explorer"). Is there such a feature in NetBeans?

Answer (score 54):

In NetBeans 6.7 it's under `View -> Synchronize` Editor with Views.

In NetBeans 8.1 it's under `View -> Synchronize` Editor with Views.

Answer (score 5):

From within the file you want to link, you can press Ctrl+Shift+1, +2, or +3. Pressing 1 navigates to the current file in the Projects tab/tree, 2 to the file in the Files tree, 3 to Favorites.

This can also be done from right click > Select in Projects, > Select in Files, > Select in Favorites, and from Navigate > Select in Projects etc.

I'm using NetBeans 6.5.1 (which *doesn't* have the View > Synchronize option).

Answer (score 0):

In NetBeans 6.9.1, the synchronization between view and editor appear only after you show the file in editor.

If you have disable the "Synchronize Editor with Views" option, you must enable (with your shortkey for example), and two times CTRL+TAB for switch between other file and return to link file in editor !

So, there is no equivalent of the eclipse fonction "link with editor".